# jq always gives null with the json file instead of value

Tags: jq

folks,
I am trying to use jq to get the json values from the json file, It should give me t1, t2 and t3 but it gives me null value. I have included the json file below, I tried doing jq various options. I want to get the t1, t2, t3 values from the field 'name' and then assign the values to a array which is variable so that I can refer to the array and do a POST.

```
 jq '.name' good.json
null

$ cat good.json 

    {
   "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualcollectionstate",
   "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual?ver=12.0.0",
   "items": [
   {
  "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
  "name": "t1",
  "partition": "Common",
  "fullPath": "/Common/t1",
  "generation": 124,
  "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t1?ver=12.0.0",
  "addressStatus": "yes",
  "autoLasthop": "default",
  "cmpEnabled": "yes",
  "connectionLimit": 0,
  "destination": "/Common/3.3.3.3:80",
  "enabled": true,
  "gtmScore": 0,
  "ipProtocol": "tcp",
  "mask": "255.255.255.255",
  "mirror": "disabled",
  "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
  "nat64": "disabled",
  "rateLimit": "disabled",
  "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
  "rateLimitMode": "object",
  "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
  "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
  "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
  "sourceAddressTranslation": {
    "type": "none"
  },
  "sourcePort": "preserve",
  "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
  "translateAddress": "enabled",
  "translatePort": "enabled",
  "vlansDisabled": true,
  "vsIndex": 21,
  "policiesReference": {
    "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t1/policies?ver=12.0.0",
    "isSubcollection": true
  },
  "profilesReference": {
    "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t1/profiles?ver=12.0.0",
    "isSubcollection": true
    }
    },
   {
  "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
  "name": "t2",
  "partition": "Common",
  "fullPath": "/Common/t2",
  "generation": 178,
  "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t2?ver=12.0.0",
  "addressStatus": "yes",
  "autoLasthop": "default",
  "cmpEnabled": "yes",
  "connectionLimit": 0,
  "destination": "/Common/4.4.4.4:80",
  "enabled": true,
  "gtmScore": 0,
  "ipProtocol": "tcp",
  "mask": "255.255.255.255",
  "mirror": "disabled",
  "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
  "nat64": "disabled",
  "rateLimit": "disabled",
  "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
  "rateLimitMode": "object",
  "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
  "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
  "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
  "sourceAddressTranslation": {
    "type": "none"
  },
  "sourcePort": "preserve",
  "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
  "translateAddress": "enabled",
  "translatePort": "enabled",
  "vlansDisabled": true,
  "vsIndex": 22,
  "policiesReference": {
    "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t2/policies?ver=12.0.0",
    "isSubcollection": true
  },
  "profilesReference": {
    "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t2/profiles?ver=12.0.0",
    "isSubcollection": true
    }
   },
   {
  "kind": "tm:ltm:virtual:virtualstate",
  "name": "t3",
  "partition": "Common",
  "fullPath": "/Common/t3",
  "generation": 179,
  "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t3?ver=12.0.0",
  "addressStatus": "yes",
  "autoLasthop": "default",
  "cmpEnabled": "yes",
  "connectionLimit": 0,
  "destination": "/Common/5.5.5.5:80",
  "enabled": true,
  "gtmScore": 0,
  "ipProtocol": "tcp",
  "mask": "255.255.255.255",
  "mirror": "disabled",
  "mobileAppTunnel": "disabled",
  "nat64": "disabled",
  "rateLimit": "disabled",
  "rateLimitDstMask": 0,
  "rateLimitMode": "object",
  "rateLimitSrcMask": 0,
  "serviceDownImmediateAction": "none",
  "source": "0.0.0.0/0",
  "sourceAddressTranslation": {
    "type": "none"
  },
  "sourcePort": "preserve",
  "synCookieStatus": "not-activated",
  "translateAddress": "enabled",
  "translatePort": "enabled",
  "vlansDisabled": true,
  "vsIndex": 23,
  "policiesReference": {
    "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t3/policies?ver=12.0.0",
    "isSubcollection": true
  },
  "profilesReference": {
    "link": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/~Common~t3/profiles?ver=12.0.0",
    "isSubcollection": true
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"name" is not a top-level key.  Consider instead:

```
$ jq '.items[] | .name' good.json
"t1"
"t2"
"t3"
```